# get a value stored an internal function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I would like to know if it is possible to recover from an external function a value stored in an internal function.

here is the code:

```
$('#down').click(function(){ 
    test();
    console.log(d); //d is not defined
});

function test(){
    $(".block").each(function(ind, ele) {
        var block = $(ele);
        // ....
        var d = $(block).attr("id");
    });
}

$(window).on("resize", test);
```

depending on the resizing "var d" assumes different value that I need to use in the click function.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to save d to a variable accessible to the scope of both functions:

```
(function() {
    var d;
    $('#down').click(function(){ 
        test();
        console.log(d); //d is now set
    });

    function test(){
        $(".block").each(function(ind, ele) {
            var block = $(ele);
            // ....
            d = $(block).attr("id");
        });
    }

    $(window).on("resize", test);
})();
```

By wrapping both functions inside another function it limits the scope of d to just those two functions.

Note that it will only be the last set value of d that will be accessible in your click event handler.